# PHP Auto-Delete file After Link Delete?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am trying to create a system where someone inputs their name, it makes a page for the person and puts a link to their page on another page called pages.php.

I got all of it working up to the posting onto pages.php working, and the only thing not working is that I want the link on pages.php to remove whenever their page/file gets removed from the server, so I won't have dead links all over pages.php.

How would I go about that?
I've tried this
**PHP**

```
        if (file_exists($FILENAME)) {
        $OPENPENDTOPICSPATH = '../pending-topics/pages.php';
        $OPENPENDTOPICS = fopen($OPENPENDTOPICSPATH, "a+");
        $PENDTOPICWRITE = '
            <div align="center">
                <a href="' . $FILENAME . '">
                    <p id="' . $FILENAME . '"><? echo rand(0, 5000); ?> ' . $NAME . '</p>
                </a><br>
            </div>
        ';
        fwrite($OPENPENDTOPICS, $PENDTOPICWRITE);
        fclose($OPENPENDTOPICS);
    } else {
        $REMOVETOPICCONTENT = '
            <script>
                $("#' . $FILENAME . ').remove();
            </script>
        ';
        fopen($OPENPENDTOPICSPATH, "r+");
        fwrite($OPENPENDTOPICS, $REMOVETOPICCONTENT);
        fclose($OPENPENDTOPICS);
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: This sounds like it might be better served to do a possible .htaccess rewrite and save this into a database rather than modify some file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not necessary. There's no reason to write this code to files when you can just have one php file that displays variables.

Save your page data to a database and fill in the variables in the page dynamically from the database.

You can even still give each page a unique url by using a descriptive title in the get parameters.

And you can gather the names from the database to make your links too.